# mysql_insert_id function is returning 0

Tags: php

I have been trying to figure out why this function is working on chrome, but not on firefox.

I have an auto increment field that is my primary key that I get my id from. Here is my code.

```
if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $id = $_GET['id'];
} else {
    $id = mysql_insert_id();
    echo $id;
}
```

I've tried putting my connection in the function as follows, but it still does not work. Any pointers would be appreciated. Also, I know of mysqli functions, I am using these functions because the user's setup is quite old.

```
$id = mysql_insert_id($conn);
```

Here is my code that is doing the insert.

```
sprintf("INSERT INTO `trade_show_orders` (`SetupDate`,`SetupEndDate`,`ShowName`,`Location`,`Literature`,`StartDate`,`EndDate`,`Attendees`,`Projected`,`File`,`Giveaways`,`AddressBox`,`LocationType`,`Title`,`FirstName`,`LastName`,`Email`,`AddressOne`,`AddressTwo`,`Zip`,`Special`,`OrderDate`,`ShippingLocation`,`ShippingAddressOne`,`ShippingAddressTwo`,`ShippingZip`,`ShippingSpecial`) VALUES ('$setupDate','$endSetup','%s','%s','$values','$eventStart','$eventEnd','%d','%d','".basename($_FILES['fileUpload']['name'])."', '%s','off','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%s','%d','%s',NOW(),'%s','%s','%s','%d','%s')", mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['showName']), mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['location']), $_POST['numberAttendees'], $_POST['visitors'], mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['giveaways']), mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['locationType']), mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['personalTitle']), mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['personalFirstName']), mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['personalLastName']), mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['personalEmail']), mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['personalAddressOne']), mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['personalAddressTwo']), $_POST['personalZip'], mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['personalSpecial']), mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['shippingLocation']), mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['shippingAddressOne']), mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['shippingAddressTwo']), $_POST['shippingZip'], mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['shippingSpecial']));
```

Comment: That function can't depend on browser at all. It depends only if you inserted something into the database or not. If you haven't inserted a thing, of course you'll get a 0.

Comment: Well, I can see it's working on chrome and not firefox. I know it shouldn't matter, but its what I am getting.

Comment: Indeed, the only way it could work in one browser and not another is if one browser sent different information to the server. So you're missing some critical components to troubleshoot this:  the javascript error, the javascript code, and the data getting posted (also the code that accepts the posts on the server)

Comment: I've inserted data into the database at this point. I can verify it in two ways, one the data is there and two I can see the query dumped out on my screen which does work when testing.

Comment: The function returns ID generated for an AUTO_INCREMENT column by the previous query on success, 0 if the previous query does not generate an AUTO_INCREMENT value

Answer (score 2):

`mysql_insert_id()` will only return an ID if you've done an `INSERT` query WITH THE CURRENT CONNECTION. That means it will not return an ID from a page request "three clicks" ago. it will not return an ID done by some other script that's executing at the same, because that's done using a different connection to mysql.

So show the rest of the code that actually does the insert. PHP shouldn't care at all what browser's running on the remote it. It's just an HTTP request with some data as far as PHP is concerned. If there is a browser-specific issue, it'll be in some client-side code that's blowing up, e.g. some bad javascript doing an AJAX request and not filling out a field properly.

Comment: did you check if the query accutally succeeds? e.g. `$result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error())`?

Comment: Yeah, it does succeed. I have tested numerous times on the insert.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it had nothing to do with my insert.

Apparently, when you use images with submits on a form in Firefox, IE. It renames the image submit from "submit" to "submit_x" or "submit_y"

Chrome and Safari look for both submit and submit_x,submit_y with images.

Firefox and IE 7,8,9 only look for submit_x and submit_y, which explains the reason why it was only working on chrome.